# kafka consumer how to force refresh metadata in order to discover new topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using regex pattern to subscribe a group of topics, which might be created dynamically. However, there might be quite a while before the consumer discovers the new created topics.

I can set the `topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms` property to change the polling intervals, but I'm concerned that short intervals might lead to overhead. So I think a notification approach would be better, i.e, when a new topic is created, the creator will notify the consumer service.

I'm looking for an API forcing the consumer to refresh its topic metadata. Didn't find a after looking through kafka Consumer APIs...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only API for this would be to `.close()` the consumer and re-`subscribe` it upon receiving such "notification event"